# PostgreSQL, ошибка при INSERT/UPDATE

Tags: postgresql

При создании таблиц и присвоении значений

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS operators
(
    id              uuid            not null unique default uuid_generate_v4(),
    name            varchar(255)    not null,
    surname         varchar(255)    not null,
    town            varchar(255)    not null,
    telephone       bigint          not null unique check (telephone >= 80000000000 and telephone <= 89999999999),
    email           varchar(255)    not null unique,
    password        varchar(255)    not null
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects
(
    id          uuid            not null unique default uuid_generate_v4(),
    name        varchar(255)    not null unique,
    typeProject varchar(255)    not null check (typeProject = 'входящий' OR typeProject = 'исходящий' OR typeProject = 'автоинформатор')
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS project_operators_list
(
    id              serial          not null,
    operators_id    uuid            not null references operators (id) on delete cascade,
    project_id      uuid            not null references projects (id) on delete cascade
);

INSERT INTO project_operators_list (operators_id, project_id) VALUES ('d821f3d8-8995-40fc-9600-455440008b5a', '34ce163a-bf05-4f5a-9065-cf010d5a64a1');
```

Выдает ошибку в последней строчке.

> [23503] ERROR: insert or update on table "project_operators_list" violates foreign key constraint "project_operators_list_operators_id_fkey" Подробности: Key (operators_id)=(d821f3d8-8995-40fc-9600-455440008b5a) is not present in table "operators".

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Устранить проблему. Вставить предварительно указанные в UPDATE значения в таблицы operators и projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он ругается что в таблице Operators нет такого значения, которое вы добавляете в таблицу project_operators_list. Видимо поле operators_id - это fk на таблицу Operators. Сначала заполните Operators